# Cygwin: How do I paste text into vi editor

Tags: unix, cygwin, vi

I am trying to paste copied text into vi editor using cygwin.  I have copied text from notepad and am trying to paste it into my vi text editor that I have open in cygwin.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

press shift+insert

Shift-Insert